# Javascript to Java

Tags: javascript, java, compilation, abstract-syntax-tree, transpiler

For the moment we are migrating from an old system using javascript for both backend and frontend code that is stored in a database and that code is interpreted by an external hidden api so we don't know the engine that executes it.

Since the new stack is based on java we thought about transpiling those javascript scripts into java classes and then code the remaning engine and needed methodes for it to run.

The problem is that there is no transpiler as far as I know from javascript to Java.

PS: the code to be converted  is relatively simple with basic loops, if and function calls there is no inheritance.

the solution I though about is:

- generate javascript AST with @babel
- transform that AST into another one compatible with a java parser
- use the compatible AST to generate java code (I couldnt find any library that does this)

Comment: Another possible solution: Generate nothing but instead completely re-write your back-end code using Java and your backend framework of choice, such as Spring. Yes, you will likely need to do some programming to solve this.

Comment: There is a very good reason we normally do not check-in autogenerated code. The reason is: most autogenerated code is horrible to read and understand. So if we go down the road of transpiling from one language to another, I heavily suspect that the code will be unreadable, hard to undrestand and even harder to maintain. I would side with @HovercraftFullOfEels on this one: in the long term, it is most likely better to rewrite.

Comment: I am no expert in Java or JavaScript backend coding (I am using PHP right now), but wouldn't this change necessitate changing backend framework, say from Node.js to Spring, or something similar? And if so, how could there possibly be any transpiled or translated solution? Please let me know if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: What exactly is the *question*?

Comment: If the code is that simple, you're probably best off just doing the translation yourself, since you can make all the ladjustments (big and small) you'll need to make it fit your new server-side environment. Separately, I can't imagine it would really be a useful path, but you could use [Java's scripting support](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/22/docs/api/java.scripting/javax/script/package-summary.html) to run the JavaScript code in Java.